# Run IIS or A Windows Server OS

Tags: iis, windows-server-2008

I know that now-a-days just about any PC is powerful enough to run any modern WS OS.  But my question being is, why would you choose running a WS OS over just simply running IIS on your PC?

I would be using this solely for printer sharing and hosting 3 websites (using the .NET framework).

Comment: its a few 100 visits a month, you can get away with hosting them on ur PC.

Comment: @LuckyChingi - so if page visits is <= 100 every 30 days a IIS would suffice?

Comment: yes, should be good.

Comment: That's how they decided in the past that IIS should be part of the server OS for production and desktop OS for development. In you don't care much about performance and so on, of course you can use desktop Windows to host your sites.